# set key with new bulkloader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backup, bulkloader

I am converting a script to use the new [bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuration_File_Reference_Details). (What was wrong
with the original bulkloader? - I prefer writing Python to editing
configuration files...)

Anyway, I want to prevent duplicates by assigning a combination of
properties to the key.
The docs say:

> If you want to use or calculate a key
>   from the import data, specify a key
>   using the same syntax as the property
>   map; that is, external_name,
>   import_template, and so on.

All the examples apply a transform to the current property. How do I
instead use a combination of other properties?

Should be something like:

```
- property: __key__
  external_name: key
  import_transform: entity.first_name + entity.last_name
```

Comment: A detailed example for future reference: http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the 'import_template' property (documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Configuration_File_Reference_Details)) instead of 'import_transform':

```
- property: __key__
  import_template: "%(first_name)s %(last_name)s"
```

Comment: thanks. Documentation needs more varied examples. It is not clear how a lot of those properties work.